# Can someone please tell me in Big Bird terminology what a clock interrupt is?

Tags: io, interrupt, clock

I also am having a hard time understanding how I/O interrupts work, but I have a better handle on them than I have on clock interrupts. Thanks my nerds!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
ELMO: la la la laaa, la la laaaa, Elmos....
COUNT: 1 O'clock MUHAHAHA
ELMO: ...song la la la...
COUNT: 2 O'Clock MUHAHAHA
ELMO: ...la la Elmos song
```

basicly, its an interrupt that is triggered off the clock, so you can do something ( like multitasking ) based on a clock.